# why the Input is 0 of layer conv1_conv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

I'm using ResNet50 but I get an error :

```
Input 0 of layer "conv1_pad" is incompatible
```

I tried to use reshape but I still get the error. What's the problem? ......................

Full code:

```
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(  data, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
    
    

np.stack((X_train,)*3, axis=-1)
np.stack((y_train,)*3, axis=-1)

        
    resnet_model = Sequential()
    
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top= False, weights="imagenet",input_tensor=None, input_shape=(512, 512, 3), pooling='avg',classes=2)

for layer in pretrained_model.layers: 
  layer.trainable = False

resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(Flatten())
resnet_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
resnet_model.summary()


resnet_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])



 history = resnet_model.fit(x= X_train, y= y_train, validation_split=0.02, epochs=10)
```

ValueError: in user code:

```
ValueError: in user code:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 214, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
```

---

**ValueError:**

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "resnet50" (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "conv1_pad" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 512, 512)

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 512, 512), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

**.....................................................OUTPUT .................................................**

```
    Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 resnet50 (Functional)       (None, 2048)              23587712  
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 2048)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 512)               1049088   
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 513       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 24,637,313
Trainable params: 1,049,601
Non-trainable params: 23,587,712
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 512, 512, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='resnet50_input'), name='resnet50_input', description="created by layer 'resnet50_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 512, 512).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 512, 512, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 512, 512).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your train data has shape `(None, 512, 512, 1)` but the model expects the shape `(None, 512, 512, 3)`

Comment: @AndrzejO thanks,  How I fix that ? I tried ->  X_train.reshape(-1,512,512,**3**) but I get error in reshape . X_train is grayScale images

Comment: and If I use ResNet50( ...,  input_shape=(512, 512, 1) ,...) I getValueError: The input must have 3 channels; Received `input_shape=(512, 512, 1)

Comment: Use `numpy.stack()` to create three channels from one ---> `np.stack((X_train,)*3, axis=-1)`

Comment: @Djinn Thank you, I tried it but I still get the same error. I edited the Question with the output.

Comment: You're not passing input with the correct shape. Show the code that generates the error, not just the error.

Comment: it's the same code above. the line that generates the error  : history = resnet_model.fit(x= X_train, y= y_train, validation_split=0.02, epochs=10)

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you applied the stack function. The problem could be when you do that, because the error message shown doesn't match what the output of np.stack would be. So please show your full code.

Comment: @Djinn  I edited the code above(in Question ) after using stack. It's after split function

Comment: You're using [`numpy.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) incorrectly. The new shape should be a tuple.

Comment: I remove reshape but I still get error , but different layer : Input 0 of layer "conv1_pad" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 512, 512)

Comment: @Djinn how can I be sure that I pass the input correctly?

Comment: What's the output of `X_train.shape`? The error shown in the question still doesn't match the output of stack.

Comment: @Djinn Thank you for your help.....  I changed the entire code and it's working now without error. I think the main problem is the data that I use is greyScale and calling Resnet it must be 3 channels 'colored images'. (You can find the code in Answer )